# How can I optimize the MPI code for the K-meas algorithm?

Tags: c, mpi

I have to create a paper for the university and the goal is to start from an MPI code to evaluate the execution times and subsequently optimize the code, and to perform the measurement of the execution time again.
I implemented this code to be able to parallelize the K-means algorithm in MPI.

The question I want to ask you is how can I optimize the underlying code to improve performance? I can't understand how I can do it.

Maybe it is possible to replace the various MPI_Send and MPI_Recv calls to improve the communication between the various processes and therefore make it lighter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define SEED 9999

typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Punto;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int rank, size;             

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

MPI_Datatype MPI_PUNTO;
MPI_Datatype type=MPI_DOUBLE;
int blocklen=2;
MPI_Aint disp=0;
MPI_Type_create_struct(1,&blocklen,&disp,&type,&MPI_PUNTO);
MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_PUNTO);

if(rank==0){

    //CODE FOR MASTER
    char *pathInput,*pathOutput;
    int i,j,flag,resto;        
    int nCentroidi;            
    int nPunti,numero_di_punti;
    int nSlave;
    int nPuntiSlave;
    Punto* punti;               
    Punto* centroidi;           
    Punto* nuovi_centroidi;    
    int* suddivisione_attuale;  
    int* ex_suddivisione;       
    int* slave_cluster;         
    double start_time,end_time;

    nCentroidi = 20;
    nPunti = 3200000;
    pathInput = "/home/rob/eclipse-workspace/Test/in.txt";
  
    FILE *input;
    input=fopen(pathInput,"r");

    punti=(Punto*)malloc(sizeof(Punto)*nPunti);

    // riempio il vettore di punti con i dati presenti nel cluster
    for(i=0; i<nPunti;i++)
        fscanf(input,"%lf,%lf",&punti[i].x,&punti[i].y);
    fclose(input);
  
    centroidi=malloc(sizeof(Punto)*nCentroidi);
    nuovi_centroidi = malloc(sizeof(Punto)*nCentroidi);
    suddivisione_attuale=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nPunti);
    ex_suddivisione=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nPunti);
    srand(SEED);

    printf("\t - Inizializzazione vettori centroidi... \n");
    for(i=0;i<nCentroidi;i++)
    {
        centroidi[i].x=((double)(rand()%1000))/1000;
        centroidi[i].y=((double)(2*rand()%1000))/1000;
    }

    printf("\t - Inizializzazione vettori cluster... \n");
    for(i=0;i<nPunti;i++)
    {
        suddivisione_attuale[i]=-1;
        ex_suddivisione[i]=-1;
    }

    flag=1;
    nSlave= size-1;
    nPuntiSlave = nPunti / nSlave;
    resto = nPunti % nSlave;

    start_time = MPI_Wtime();
    // Invio a tutti i slave i parametri iniziali
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        numero_di_punti = nPuntiSlave;
        if(i == size-1 && resto != 0){
            numero_di_punti += resto;
        }
        MPI_Send(&flag,0,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&numero_di_punti,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&nCentroidi,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(punti+(i-1)*nPuntiSlave,numero_di_punti, MPI_PUNTO,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    do{

        // invio i centroidi agli slave
        for(i=1;i<size;i++){
            MPI_Send(centroidi,nCentroidi, MPI_PUNTO,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        // Ricevo i risultati dagli slave
        for(i=1;i<size;i++){
            numero_di_punti = nPuntiSlave;
            if(i == size-1 && resto != 0)
                numero_di_punti += resto;
            MPI_Recv(suddivisione_attuale+(i-1)*nPuntiSlave,numero_di_punti,MPI_INT  ,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        }

        int convergenza = 1;

        for(i=0;i<nPunti;i++)
        {
            if(suddivisione_attuale[i]!=ex_suddivisione[i])
                {
                    convergenza=0;
                    i=nPunti;
                }
        }

        if(convergenza){
            flag=0;
        }else{
            
            int* popolazione=malloc(sizeof(int)*nCentroidi);

            for(i=0;i<nCentroidi;i++)
            {
                popolazione[i]=0;
                nuovi_centroidi[i].x=0;
                nuovi_centroidi[i].y=0;
            }
            for(i=0;i<nPunti;i++)
            {
                popolazione[suddivisione_attuale[i]]++;
                nuovi_centroidi[suddivisione_attuale[i]].x=nuovi_centroidi[suddivisione_attuale[i]].x+punti[i].x;
                nuovi_centroidi[suddivisione_attuale[i]].y=nuovi_centroidi[suddivisione_attuale[i]].y+punti[i].y;
            }
            for(i=0;i<nCentroidi;i++)
            {
                if(popolazione[i]!=0.0)
                {
                    nuovi_centroidi[i].x=nuovi_centroidi[i].x/popolazione[i];
                    nuovi_centroidi[i].y=nuovi_centroidi[i].y/popolazione[i];
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<nCentroidi;i++)
            {
                centroidi[i].x=nuovi_centroidi[i].x;
                centroidi[i].y=nuovi_centroidi[i].y;
            }


            for(i=0;i<nPunti;i++)
                ex_suddivisione[i]=suddivisione_attuale[i];
        }

        for(i=1;i<size;i++){
            MPI_Send(&flag,1,MPI_INT,i,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

    }while(flag);
    end_time = MPI_Wtime();
 
}else{
    // SLAVE CODE


    int i,j,flag;    // variabili contatore e bandiera utilizzate durante le varie fasi
    int nCentroidi;   // # di cluster in cui si vuole suddividere l'insieme di elementi
    int nPunti;                 // # di elementi da suddividere
    Punto* punti;               // vettore contenente i punti da suddividere in cluster
    Punto* centroidi;           // vettore contenente i centroidi
    int* suddivisione_attuale;  // vettore contenente i centroidi per ogni punto nell'attuale suddivisione


    MPI_Recv(&flag,1,MPI_INT  ,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&nPunti,1,MPI_INT  ,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    MPI_Recv(&nCentroidi,1,MPI_INT  ,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

    punti=(Punto*)malloc(sizeof(Punto)*nPunti);
    suddivisione_attuale=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*nPunti);
    centroidi=malloc(sizeof(Punto)*nCentroidi);

    MPI_Recv(punti,nPunti,MPI_PUNTO,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

    do{

        MPI_Recv(centroidi,nCentroidi,MPI_PUNTO,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

        for(i=0; i < nPunti; i++){
            int cluster = 0;
            double distanza = 0;
            double distanza_minima = (pow((punti[i].x-centroidi[0].x)*100,2)+pow((punti[i].y-centroidi[0].y)*100,2));  // calcolo come distanza minima quella tra il punto e il primo centroide

            for(j=1;j<nCentroidi;j++){
                distanza = pow((punti[i].x-centroidi[j].x)*100,2)+pow((punti[i].y-centroidi[j].y)*100,2);
                if(distanza <= distanza_minima){
                    cluster = j;
                    distanza_minima = distanza;
                }
            }
            suddivisione_attuale[i]= cluster;
        }

        //invio i risultati al master
        MPI_Send(suddivisione_attuale,nPunti, MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        //Leggo il flag per determinare se continuare le iterazioni o terminare l'esecuzione
        MPI_Recv(&flag,1,MPI_INT,0,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }while(flag);
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't use send/recv to spread the data: use scatter. But really, creating all data on process zero is a bottleneck. Let each process create its own data.

Comment: First you must understand where the time is spent in your code. Is this in a serial region (in this case, can you parallelize it?) is this in communications? computations? is there load imbalance? how does the number of MPI tasks impact this? What is a typical dataset and number of tasks?